# Is there a way to speed up the access to MS SQL Server remotly over a 128KB/64KB?

Tags: c#, vb.net, sql-server-2008, ado.net

I have a MS SQL Server and 3 client machines, And a program that
works on client machines and fetch the data from the MS SQL Server
over a 128KBs/64KBs connection speed.

The program works fine but the data fetching and submitting is slow.

I'm asking about any method or idea or technique that can speed up the the access to the MS SQL Server for example database caching or anything like, So that the program can access the database As if it was on the same client machine.

I'm using .net framework 4, vb.net, c#, MS SQL Server 2008 R8, ado.net, Windows 7

Answer (score 2):

Depending on our data integrity needs, you could consider the [Microsoft Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb736753), which would allow you to access a local copy of your database (e.g., stored in SQL Express or SQL Compact) and synchronize back the changes intermittently.

Comment: Sync framework is very flexible, I use it as well, if local sync is the only option, I highly suggest it over in house developed methods. It can lead to confusion though over authority in situations where data is updated frequently and connections are slow.

Comment: Thanks Philipp Schmid and Sabre for your help...
But could you tell me: Is Microsoft Sync Framework available with Ms Access as well?

Answer (score 1):

Very much depends on what data you are moving and what the scope of the project is. Sending queries across and returning data in compressed serialized datasets can save a lot of bandwidth. However it would require a service or application on the server side as well.

I have done this over long (10 or more miles) or radio shots where bandwidth was sacrificed for stability.

The reduction in bandwidth depends on volume of data and how well it compresses (Generally a measure of how repetitive it is).

I have a class that will serialize and compress, then decompress and de serialize data sets if you are interested.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Sabre's idea, I ran into a situation where call centers around Africa had to connect back to a data center in South Africa over a very slow satellite link.

We got considerable additional throughput by using dedicated compression/decompression devices on each end of the connection.

Could be viable in your situation and would not require a code change.

Answer (score 0):

Buy faster connection.
Add caching.

Comment: Thank your for your help but I've a question. How to add caching?

Comment: Sumek: Not really helpful to tell a programmer to buy a faster connection.  There are many situations around the world where a faster connection just isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

Don't connect to the database to store info until you absolutely need to.  In other words, try running the calculations before hand.

Next, batch your sql commands so that the network round trips are reduced.

Comment: Thanks for your help but...
That solution won't help me a lot.
The MS SQL Server holds a store data and I need to fetch the latest data from the database.